# Consuming WCF using IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

I seem to be having issues consuming my WCF hosted on IIS.
When going straight to it in the browser, I get the "Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled." but all the steps it points out I should try, they don't work. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I can take another step on debugging it. My Web.config is below.
(This is using WD Express 2010 if it makes a difference)

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Service">
        <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="httpEndPoint" contract="IService1"/>
        <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" name="webEndPoint" contract="IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" contract="IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
       </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```